# Php Javascript Alert on Login

Tags: javascript, php

I need to notify the user that they logged in successfully with a pop alert to the following code. Anyone any pointers how I can add it to the php below?

Thanks.

```
function logged_in_redirect() {
    if (logged_in() === true) 
    {
        header('Location: /index.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
function logged_in_redirect() {
    if (logged_in()) 
    {
        echo "<script>alert('You are successfully Logged in');</script>";
        echo "<script>location.href='/index.php';</script>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the notification to the page through get or save it to the session and then unset it. The second option is a bit harder to implement but it's less intrusive for the user (won't clutter the url).

**Through GET**

```
function logged_in_redirect() {
    if (logged_in() === true) 
    {
        $successMessage = urlencode('Authenticated successfully');
        header('Location: ' . sprintf('/index.php?message=%1$s', $successMessage));
        exit();
    }
}
```

On index.php you can access the message through `$_GET['message']` and display it on the page.

**Through the session**

First of all start the session (if it's not started already: `session_start();`.

```
function logged_in_redirect() {
    if (logged_in() === true) 
    {
        $_SESSION['successMessage'] = 'Authenticated successfully';
        header('Location: /index.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

In index.php you will have something like this (don't forget to start the session, otherwise the usperglobal `$_SESSION` will not be available):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['successMessage'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['successMessage'];
    unset($_SESSION['successMessage'];
}
```

As for the JavaScript part, you can echo the message inside the JavaScript code for the alert. However, I highly suggest you look at a templating engine (Smarty or Twig) for the HMTL/JS instead of using echo as in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function logged_in_redirect() {
    if (logged_in()) 
    {
        echo "<script>alert('You are successfully Logged in');
        location.href='/index.php';</script>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put alert("You are Logged in Successfully"); in between Script tags

OR

Call a function in onload event in body tag of html

write a function in script with same alert() looks like above.

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
function logged_in_redirect() {
    if (logged_in() === true) 
    {
       ?>
         <script>    alert("logged in");  </script>
<?php
        header( "refresh:5; url=index.php" );
        exit();
    }
}
```

?>